# How to use order by with multiple isdescendantnode

Tags: aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I am attempting to grab multiple nodes of the same type from different areas in the jcr and order them by a date.

```
SELECT * FROM [social:asiResource] 
WHERE [sling:resourceType] = 'social/qna/components/hbs/topic' AND 
[isFeatured_b] = true AND 
NOT CONTAINS([cq:tags],'administrative:blacklist') AND 
(ISDESCENDANTNODE([/path/to/content]) OR 
ISDESCENDANTNODE([/path/to/content]))
ORDER BY [cq:lastModified] DESC
```

This will return me the correct set of results but not in the correct order. In fact altering `DESC` to `ASC` does not alter the results in any way.

My solution currently is to do multiple queries and perform a union which allows `ORDER BY` to function like it should.

```
SELECT * FROM [social:asiResource] 
WHERE [sling:resourceType] = 'social/qna/components/hbs/topic' AND 
[isFeatured_b] = true AND 
NOT CONTAINS([cq:tags],'administrative:blacklist') AND 
ISDESCENDANTNODE([/path/to/content]) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM [social:asiResource] WHERE 
[sling:resourceType] = 'social/qna/components/hbs/topic' AND 
[isFeatured_b] = true AND 
NOT CONTAINS([cq:tags],'administrative:blacklist') AND 
ISDESCENDANTNODE([/path/to/content])
ORDER BY [cq:lastModified] DESC
```

Unfortunately I have around 30 nodes that I am searching through making the latter query unusable. Is there a way to use `ORDER BY` without using a `UNION`?

Answer (score 0):

The initial query is now working. It seems like there was some other factors leading to the `ORDER BY` not giving valid results.

To clarify you can `ORDER BY` when using multiple `ISDESCENDANTNODE`'s.

Comment: Also `NOT CONTAINS` seems to slow down the query quite a bit.